# how can i correct this error? segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I'm new to coding and I was doing an exercise and this error came up when compiling "Segmentation fault (core dumped) and I have no idea how to correct it and I've looked up the error but I don't really understand it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{


char Kid1[12];

char Kid2[] = "Maddie";

char Kid3[7] = "Andrew";

char Hero1 = "Batman";

char Hero2[34] = "Spiderman";

char Hero3[25];

Kid1[0] = 'K';
Kid1[1] = 'a';
Kid1[2] = 't';
Kid1[3] = 'i';
Kid1[4] = 'e';
Kid1[5] = '\0';

strcpy(Hero3, "The incredible Hulk");

printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid2, Hero2);
printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid3, Hero3);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: what have you tried? maybe some debugging? https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: `char Hero1 = "Batman";` --> `char * Hero1 = "Batman";` or `char Hero1[] = "Batman";`

Comment: Guess you are using GCC. Try -Wall -Werror compilation options, this might be useful

Comment: The error will NEVER be produced while compiling.  It is a run time error, so the compiled and linked code must be running

Comment: regarding; `char Kid3[7] = "Andrew";`  it is much better to let the compiler calculate the size needed.   Suggest: `char Kid3[] = "Andrew";

Answer (score 4):

Read the compiler warnings. When the source code in the question is compiled, the compiler will warn that the statement `char Hero1 = "Batman"` attempts to convert a `char *` or `char [7]` to  `char`. It attempts to assign a string to a `char`.

When you ignore the warning and run the program, the address of the string will be converted in some way to a `char`.

A good compiler will also warn that `printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);` passes a `char` (`Hero1`) where `printf` is expected a string (pointer to a `char`) for `%s`. Since the `char` you are passing does not contain a proper pointer, `printf` gets a bad address, and this causes the segment fault.

Change `char Hero1 = "Batman";` to `char *Hero1 = "Batman";`. Pay attention to compiler messages.

Answer (score 0):

I agree:

> Change char Hero1 = "Batman"; to char *Hero1 = "Batman";. Pay attention to compiler messages.

But I think more accurately const char *Hero1 = "Batman";